# Django: add checksum on models

Tags: django, checksum, crc, data-integrity, 21cfr11

In a Django app I need to check data integrity (that is I want to detect if someone has altered the content of a record from outside the application [e.g. by changing data by hand in the DB]).

My idea is to add a "checksum" on each model instance (either an additional field on the model or on a linked "checksum" model).

So, I have two questions:

1. Is this a good solution?
2. Is there any django application ready for this purpose? (I didn't find anything)

Thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. It depends on how you're storing the data, how the data might be changed externally, and what you intend to do when it changes.

Comment: @dm03514 Ok, but the user has to be warned that someone has altered his data (this is required by 21CFR11 http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfCFR/CFRSearch.cfm?CFRPart=11&showFR=1)

Comment: Well, many database systems will let you define triggers which perform an action when the data is changed. This would probably be a lot simpler than a custom solution. However, it still may not be enough for 21CFR11 compliancy.

Answer (score 1):

I find it's a good solution. You could create a `Checksum` model with a `Generic Foreign Key`, then create a listener for the `post_save` signal, to update the Checksum of the saved object. But you'll still have to consider bulk updates within Django and change your models' default `Manager`s to make atomic updates on querysets.

I kind of do something similar to keep track of every models with an UUID in my project.